# MinMaxScaling not returning proper values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a large array (shape is (125501, 34000)), that I'm trying to use MinMaxScaling on, but the outputted scaled array is completely wrong:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 

print dataset
[[  124    77 10743 ...    28    56     1]
 [    0     0   189 ...     0     0     0]
 [    0     0  1518 ...     0     0     0]
 ...
 [    1     0     0 ...     0     0     0]
 [   35     5     2 ...     0     0     0]
 [   29     8     1 ...     2     1     0]]

mx = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled = mx.fit_transform(dataset)

print scaled
[[0.99988379 0.99997088 0.99958496 ... 0.99999933 0.99996154 0.99999913]
 [0.99988374 0.99997084 0.99958004 ... 0.99999931 0.99996151 0.99999913]
 [0.99988374 0.99997084 0.99958066 ... 0.99999931 0.99996151 0.99999913]
 ...
 [0.99988374 0.99997084 0.99957995 ... 0.99999931 0.99996151 0.99999913]
 [0.99988375 0.99997084 0.99957996 ... 0.99999931 0.99996151 0.99999913]
 [0.99988375 0.99997084 0.99957996 ... 0.99999931 0.99996151 0.99999913]]
```

All of the output values seem to sit somewhere between 0.996 and 0.999, even though that clearly can't be the case. For example, the max values for each feature is:

```
print mx.data_max_
[249706.  62620. 902419. ...   1475.  82652.   1879.]
```

The first column has some very small values (e.g. 124, 0, 35, etc) in comparison to the max value (249706), but the output is still ~0.999.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Please check the minimum of your data, it's probably because you have a very large negative number.

Comment: Could you provide some summary statistics across each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason may be if there is huge difference between minimum and every other values in each feature columns (*as @Kevin Fang mentioned in the comment*). You can try with sample dataset as below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 

dataset = [[150, -1000], [125, 775], [175, 700], [-1000, 725]]
print(np.array(dataset))
```

Input dataset:

```
[[  150 -1000]
 [  125   775]
 [  175   700]
 [-1000   725]]
```

As there is difference in minimum of every column and every other number in each column in the dataset.

```
mx = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled = mx.fit_transform(dataset)
print(scaled)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.9787234   0.        ]
 [ 0.95744681  1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.95774648]
 [ 0.          0.97183099]]
```

Except minimum of each column (which is 0) , all other values are high. So, you may have to handle outliers (minimum) before processing.

From [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.transform) on how it is computed is as below:

> X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
>
> X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min

Comment: It's probably true, according to the data provided in the OP (data before and after transformation as well as max values) we can revert the scaling process and infer the minimum value per column. For the first column for example this yields `-2147574137` which is around 4 orders of magnitude larger than the max value.

Comment: I dont know how, but some extremely negative numbers slipped past my data munging / qc process. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 0):

As a small exercise we can [invert the transformation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from the data provided in the OP and hence infer the minimum values for the presented columns:

```
import numpy as np

x_before = np.array([124, 77, 10743, 28, 56, 1])
x_after = np.array([0.99988379, 0.99997088, 0.99958496, 0.99999933, 0.99996154, 0.99999913])
max_vals = np.array([249706, 62620, 902419, 1475, 82652, 1879])
min_vals = (x_before - x_after*max_vals) / (1 - x_after)
print(min_vals)
```

Which outputs:

```
[-2.14743122e+09 -2.14770524e+09 -2.14750737e+09 -2.15970002e+09
 -2.14749925e+09 -2.15861881e+09]
```

Which in turn indicates that [@student's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618120/3767239) is spot on.